# $| \int fg|\leq 1$ for any $g\in C_{0}^{\infty}$, $\|g\|_{L^{2}}=1$ then $\|f\|_{L^{2}}\leq1$

Tags: real-analysis, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

I have the following question:

Let $f$ be a continuous function in an open, bounded, smooth domain $\Omega$ in $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ such that $|  \int_{\Omega} fg|\leq 1$ for any $g\in C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$, $\|g\|_{L^{2}(\Omega)}=1$. Here the measure and the integral are w.r.t. Lebesgue measure.  And $C_{0}^{\infty}(\Omega)$ is the set of smooth functions of compact support in $\Omega$.

Can we conclude that $f\in L^{2}(\Omega)$?

Thanks for any hint.

Comment: What are we assuming about $f$ to make $\int_{\Omega} fg$ an a priori well-defined quantity? If $f$ is measurable and not in $L^1_{loc}$ already, the expression need not be defined.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou I think the hypothesis is that $\int fg$ exist and $|\int fg| \leq 1$ whenvever $g $ is smooth with compact support.

Comment: @WoolierThanThou Let me assume that $f$ is continuous on $\Omega$. I have changed the post.

Comment: what is an "smooth domain"? A convex one?

Comment: @Masacroso: It is a domain such that $\partial \Omega$ is a $C^{\infty}$-manifold.

Comment: @ Masacroso A smooth domain is a domain in which the boundary can be locally considered as a graph of a $C^{\infty}$ function. If you would like you can assume that $\Omega$ is convex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that 
\begin{align*}
T_{f}:C_{0}^{\infty}\rightarrow\mathbb{C},~~~~g\rightarrow\int fg,
\end{align*}
then by assumption $\|T_{f}(g)\|\leq\|g\|_{L^{2}}$ and hence $\|T_{f}\|\leq 1$. But $C_{0}^{\infty}$ is dense in $L^{2}$, so there is a unique extension $\overline{T}\in(L^{2})^{\ast}$ of $T_{f}$ such that $\left\|\overline{T}\right\|=\|T_{f}\|$. By Riesz Representation Theorem, we have $(L^{2})^{\ast}=L^{2}$ in the sense that a unique $h\in L^{2}$ is such that 
\begin{align*}
\overline{T}(g)=\int hg,~~~~g\in L^{2},
\end{align*}
and that $\|h\|_{L^{2}}=\left\|\overline{T}\right\|$. It follows that $\|h\|_{L^{2}}\leq 1$ and that
\begin{align*}
\int(h-f)g=0,~~~~g\in C_{0}^{\infty}.
\end{align*}
If it were shown to be the case that $h-f=0$ a.e. then we are done.

So the matter is now to show that $\displaystyle\int fg=0$ for all $g\in C_{0}^{\infty}$ will imply that $f=0$ a.e.

First note that the existence of $\displaystyle\int fg$ entails that $\displaystyle\int|fg|<\infty$. For a fixed compact set $K$, take a nonnegative $g\in C_{0}^{\infty}$ such that $g=1$ on $K$, then $\displaystyle\int|fg|\geq\int_{K}|f|$, then $f\in L^{1}(K)$.

On the other hand, for a fixed $x$, we have $\displaystyle\int f(\cdot)\varphi_{\epsilon}(x-\cdot)=0$, where $\varphi_{\epsilon}$ is a standard nonnegative mollifier, the equation is no more than saying that $\varphi_{\epsilon}\ast f(x)=0$. As $\varphi_{\epsilon}\ast f\rightarrow f$ in $L^{1}(K)$, we have $f=0$ a.e. on $K$.

The result follows by considering an exhaustion of compact sets to the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I seem to have a proof that works assuming that $f\in L^{\infty}_{loc}(\Omega)$ (hence, in particular, if $f\in C(\Omega)$).

Indeed, let $\varphi\in C^{\infty}_0(\Omega)$ and let $(\eta_{\varepsilon})_{\varepsilon\in(0,1]}$ be a (positive) mollifier. Then, since $f\in L^{\infty}(\textrm{supp}(\varphi)),$ we have

$$
\left| \int_{\Omega} f^+ \varphi \right|=\left|\int f \varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}\right|=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \left|\int f (\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}} *\eta_{\varepsilon}) \right|\leq \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+}||\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}*\eta_{\varepsilon}||_2=||\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}||_2\leq ||\varphi||_2,
$$
where we use that $\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}} *\eta_{\varepsilon}\in C_0^{\infty}(\Omega)$ for $\varepsilon$ sufficiently small (we extend by $0$ to $\mathbb{R}^n$ when defining the convolution). We get that $f^{+}$ and, similarly, $f^{-}$ must satisfy the same property.

Hence, we can assume that $f$ is positive. Let $(K_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$ be an exhaustion of $\Omega$ by compacts and let $f_n=f1_{K_n}.$ Then, $f_n\in L^{\infty}(K_n)\subseteq L^{2}(K_n)$ and

$$
||f_n||_{L^2}^2= \int f_n^2=\lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \int f_n (f_n*\eta_{\varepsilon})\leq \limsup_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} \int f (f_n*\eta_{\varepsilon})\leq \lim_{\varepsilon\to 0^+} ||f_n*\eta_{\varepsilon}||_{L^2}=||f_n||_{L^2},
$$
implying that $||f_n||_{L^2}\in [0,1]$. Applying monotone convergence, we get that $f\in L^2(\Omega)$ and $||f||_{L^2}\leq 1.$

Comment: Actually, I guess I'm just using that $f\in L^2_{loc}(\Omega)$.

Comment: For $f\in L_{\text{loc}}^{2}$ can you really do $\displaystyle\int f\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}=\lim_{\epsilon}\displaystyle\int f(\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}\ast\eta_{\epsilon})$?

Comment: Yes: $|| f(\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}- \varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}*\eta_{\varepsilon})||_{L^1}\leq ||f (1_{\varphi *\eta_{\varepsilon}\neq 0}+1_{\varphi\neq 0})||_{L^2} ||\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}-\varphi 1_{\{f>0\}}*\eta_{\varepsilon}||_{L^2}$ by Cauchy Schwarz, and  $g *\eta_{\varepsilon}\to g$ in $L^p$ for every $p$ such that $g\in L^p$ (unless of course $p=\infty$, in which case, we need $g$ continuous).